# How to create database with sqlite and flask?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

```
from flask import Flask , render_template
import sqlite3 as db

myapp = Flask(__name__)

@myapp.route("/")
def creat_database():
    return render_template("home.html")

@myapp.route("/createdatabase",methods = ['POST','GET'])
def createdatabase():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            name = request.form['database']
            
            with db.connect(name) as con :
                msg = "Database Created Succesfully"
        except:
            con.rollback()
            msg = "Error To Create Database"
        finally:
            con.close()
            return render_template("result.html",msg = msg)
        
if (__name__)==("__main__"):
    myapp.run(debug= True , port=8900)
```

I'm tring to create database with sqlite and flask but it give me this error

NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: You're trying to use `request` but it's not imported. Include it from flask. `from flask import Flask, render_template, request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import request:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
```